# How to add android ionic platform

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I've been able to install ionic and create the necessary files for the app by "$ionic start myApp tabs" but when i tried to build the app "ionic platform add android"
i'm getting this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4HDQ.png

I've looked online for any solutions and found some with no luck

Comment: Did you read what it says? Its pretty clear.

Comment: What does it mean by "Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions."

Comment: @r2DoesInc yea how do I go about changing the path, i'm really new to this and I was just following the installation steps from the ionic website

Answer (score 1):

You will need to go to your environment variables and update the below to your path.

> android-sdk\platform-tools
>
> android-sdk\tools
>
> apache-ant-1.9.4\bin
>
> jdk1.8.0_31\bin

Depending on your OS, for windows 8 the quickest way to get to the window to edit your path is by clicking the `windows` key on your keyboard and searching environment variables. The first item in the list, `"edit environment variables for your account"` is correct. Make sure you add the full path of each of the above.

Your PATH variable should look something like this...

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users[user]\Documents\Development\sdks\apache-ant-1.9.4\bin;**%JAVA_HOME%**\bin;C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm

Where I have %JAVA_HOME% I have simply named a new variable JAVA_HOME which has the following path...

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31

I did this simply to make the string of text in PATH shorter. You can just replace, where I have %JAVA_HOME%, with C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31 or where ever your path to `jdk1.8.0_31` .

Please make sure that you put in the correct path that is relevent to where you have each of these and don't copy what I have above as this will not work for you.